# Is there a way to alias the current class instead of the using reference one?

Tags: c#

In the example below, they are conflicting class names for ClassA. Is there any way I can use `OutsideLibrary.ClassA` without needing the alias? Maybe put the alias on the other ClassA somehow?

```
using alias1 = OutsideLibrary

namespace Any.Namespace.01
{
  public class ClassA 
  {
    public void Method1(){
      alias1::ClassA.DoOperation();
    }
  }
}

namespace Different.Namespace
{
  public class ClassA { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the class including the full namespace? Example:

```
var classA1 = new Any.Namespace.01.ClassA();

var classA2 = new Different.Namespace.ClassA();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to achieve what you want.

The closest thing you can do is create an alias directly to the referenced class:

```
using OtherClassA = OutsideLibrary.Class1;

namespace Any.Namespace.01
{
    public class ClassA 
    {
        public void Method1() 
        {
            OtherClassA.DoOperation();
        }
    }
}
```